# Проблема с модулем configparser в python

Tags: python, config

Вечно вижу ошибки о том что что-то не найдено, либо файл...
Код:

```
try:
    from configparser import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser  # ver. < 3.0

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('userbot_config.ini')
api_id = config.get('section', 'api_id')
print(api_id)
```

config:

```
[section]
api_id = "0"
api_hash = "0"
#https://my.telegram.org/auth
```

Ошибка:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSectionError
No section: 'section'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Исспользуйте функцию read_file

```
config = ConfigParser()
#config.read(['userbot_config.ini'])
#or
#config.read_file(open('userbot_config.ini'))
print(config.has_section('section'))
api_id = config.get('section', 'api_id')

print(api_id)
```

Comment: Не выходит, опять ошибка:
Exception has occurred: MissingSectionHeaderError
File contains no section headers.
file: '<???>', line: 1
'u'

Comment: @Kripl исправил

Comment: В первом варианте не видит секцию, во втором не видит файл, а has_section пишет False Вот скриншот кода с ошибкой - joxi.ru/KAgNlRkt5aXlz2 Вот скриншот конфига - joxi.ru/zANbR7yU106Y8A